# Mysql select rows using cross reference but omit on a condition

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

Given these tables:

```
+---------------+---------+
| Field         | Type    |
+---------------+---------+
| group_id      | int(10) |
| subscriber_id | int(10) |
+---------------+---------+

+---------------+--------------+
| Field         | Type         |
+---------------+--------------+
| subscriber_id | int(10)      |
| firstname     | varchar(50)  |
| lastname      | varchar(50)  |
| company       | varchar(120) |
| position      | varchar(50)  |
| email         | text         |
| lettertype    | varchar(5)   |
| status        | varchar(20)  |
+---------------+--------------+
```

I used the following query to get a subset of subscribers:

```
SELECT * 
FROM newsletter_subscribe AS a, newsletter_subscriber AS b
WHERE (a.group_id = 1 or a.group_id = 4)AND (a.subscriber_id = b.subscriber_id)
```

What I'd like to do is exclude from the subset if a row exists in newsletter_subscribe where group_id = 3 then the newsletter_subscribe from that row is excluded from the result.

My thought was to make a temporary table to replace `a`, but I'm not certain how to go about it.

Comment: can you show some results?  I am not as familiar with MySQL syntax as I am with SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM newsletter_subscribe AS a, newsletter_subscriber AS b
WHERE (a.group_id = 1 or a.group_id = 4) AND (a.subscriber_id = b.subscriber_id) AND (b.subscriber_id NOT IN (SELECT subscriber_id FROM newsletter_subscribe WHERE group_id = 3))
```

Comment: @TecBrat Trust your own instincts. You virtually answered your own question with `exclude from the subset if a row exists in newsletter_subscribe where group_id = 3`! Look how simply that related directly over to a mySQL operation.

Comment: The problem was my unfamiliarity with the correct syntax. I'm far enough along to ask a good question, but need some help sometimes with the final product. Your answer will serve me for this instance, and probably many more in the future.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands now, you'll never get group_id=3, because you only allow groups `1` and `4` in the first term of your where clause. If you want ALL groups EXCEPT 3, then use

```
WHERE (a.group_id <> 3) AND (a.subscriber_id = b.subscriber_id)
```

or perhaps

```
WHERE 3 NOT IN (a.group_id, b.group_id) AND (a.subscriber_id = b.subscriber_id)
```

to exclude it from both tables.

Comment: that is what I was thinking.

Comment: A subscriber can belong to more than one group. I wanted every subscriber to group 1 and every subscriber to group 4 unless they were also a subscriber to group 3. @DevlshOne got it.